# How to filter the list using radio button in ionic1

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my case there are 3 radio button. I want to filter data when I click on first radio button PRESENT-ON TIME. It will show only ON-TIME present student only and vice-versa.

**API response is**

```
late_status=0 for on time
late_status=1 for on late
```

**My HTML file look like this**

```
`<input type="radio" name="process" ng-value="0" id="design" ng-click='present1()' ng-model="data.late_status"/><label class="choice" for="design" > Present-On Time</label><br />

<input type="radio" name="process" ng-value="1" id="late" ng-click='late1()' ng-model="data.late_status" /><label class="choice" for="late"> Present-Late</label><br />

<div ng-hide="myVar"  class="col col-20" ng-if="data.late_status == 0"><i><b>On Time</b></i>
               <!-- If block(ON TIME) -->
               </div>
              <div ng-hide="myVar"  class="col col-20" ng-if="data.late_status != 0"><i><b>Late</b></i>                         
                <!-- Your Else Block(LATE) -->
</div>`
```

controller.js file

```
  $scope.late1 = function () {



        $ionicLoading.show({

                         template: '<ion-spinner></ion-spinner><p>Loading...</p>'

                           });

        $scope.data={late_status:'1'};


            var link =
            var datasend = $.param({
                request_code: 'get'[enter image description here][1]
                start_time: '08:00:00',
                end_time: '10:00:00',
                machine_id: '101',

              //date:"17-02-2018"  
               date: today.getDate() + '/' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getFullYear()
                         });
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: so you want **TO DO** that but what is the actual issue?

Comment: Thanks for reply.  issue is when i click on any of the radio button . The list is not filtering...It shows combine student data of ON TIME and LATE.. my list consist of 4 coloumn..NAME,PHOTO,CLASS and STATUS..In the status block it shows both data.

Comment: what is `var link =` supposed to be equal to? you need something after the equals sign.

Comment: yes var link is equal to api url in my controller code.

Comment: but you can't set it like that. Try `var link = datasend;`, give that a go.

Comment: no.the problem is not with car link..The code is ok there.i haven't show the url of api here but it is written in my code..